# OpenWrt : AP stops if STA fails

Tags: configuration, switch-statement, wifi, ethernet, openwrt

I have 3 interfaces :

- LAN (WiFi AP, DHCP server)
- wan (WiFi STA(tion), DHCP client)
- wan2 (Ethernet , DHCP client)

I installed `mwan3` so, with this config, I should access Internet through wan and wan2 or just one of both if only one is online.

I tried to simulate a `ifdown` event on each interface and I still had access to Internet through the other interface. I also tried to disable the `WiFi STA` interface and all was doing fine.

BUT when I turned off the WiFi source corresponding to `WiFi STA` , `WiFi AP` stops and I was disconnected (sometimes the wifi AP reappears for a few seconds)

**EDIT** : 
Here's two **System logs**...
When I manually disable the Wifi Client Interface from OpenWrt settings and it goes fine :

```
:09 2017 kern.info kernel: [  606.720000] Wifi_Client: deauthenticating from dc:ee:06:d8:7e:43 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
 :09 2017 daemon.notice netifd: Network device 'Wifi_Client' link is down
 :09 2017 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'wan' has link connectivity loss
 :09 2017 daemon.notice netifd: Network device 'wlan0-1' link is down
 :09 2017 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'lan' has link connectivity loss
 :09 2017 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'wan' is disabled
 :09 2017 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'lan' is now down
 :09 2017 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'lan' is disabled
 :09 2017 daemon.info dnsmasq[3510]: reading /tmp/resolv.conf.auto
 :09 2017 daemon.info dnsmasq[3510]: using local addresses only for domain lan
 :09 2017 daemon.info dnsmasq[3510]: using nameserver 8.8.8.8#53
 :09 2017 daemon.info dnsmasq[3510]: using nameserver 8.8.4.4#53
 :09 2017 daemon.notice netifd: wan (3154): udhcpc: SIOCGIFINDEX: No such device
 :09 2017 daemon.notice netifd: wan (3154): Received SIGTERM
 :10 2017 user.notice mwan3: ifdown interface wan (unknown)
 :11 2017 daemon.notice netifd: radio0 (12239): Configuration file: /var/run/hostapd-phy0.conf
 :11 2017 kern.info kernel: [  608.500000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
 :11 2017 daemon.notice netifd: radio0 (12239): wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
 :11 2017 daemon.notice netifd: radio0 (12239): Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr c4:6e:1f:ab:e3:a6 and ssid "Wifi_AP"
 :12 2017 daemon.notice netifd: radio0 (12239): wlan0: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->ENABLED
 :12 2017 daemon.notice netifd: radio0 (12239): wlan0: AP-ENABLED 
 :12 2017 kern.info kernel: [  609.850000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
 :13 2017 daemon.notice netifd: Network device 'wlan0' link is up
 :13 2017 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'lan' is enabled
 :13 2017 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'lan' is setting up now
 :13 2017 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'lan' is now up
 :13 2017 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'lan' has link connectivity 
 :14 2017 user.notice firewall: Reloading firewall due to ifup of lan (wlan0)
```

When I turn off the Wifi Client Source and it goes bad :

```
:06 2017 kern.debug kernel: [ 1564.140000] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by dc:ee:06:d8:7e:43
:09 2017 kern.info kernel: [ 1566.970000] wlan0: authenticate with dc:ee:06:d8:7e:43
:09 2017 kern.info kernel: [ 1567.000000] wlan0: send auth to dc:ee:06:d8:7e:43 (try 1/3)
:09 2017 daemon.notice netifd: Network device 'wlan0-1' link is down
:09 2017 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'lan' has link connectivity loss
:09 2017 kern.info kernel: [ 1567.090000] wlan0: send auth to dc:ee:06:d8:7e:43 (try 2/3)
:09 2017 kern.info kernel: [ 1567.170000] wlan0: send auth to dc:ee:06:d8:7e:43 (try 3/3)
:10 2017 kern.info kernel: [ 1567.250000] wlan0: authentication with dc:ee:06:d8:7e:43 timed out
```